# Why type of 'int' is type?

Tags: python, types

I am printing type(int). Please explain me about this behaviour. thanks in advance.

```
print(type(int))
```

Comment: `>>> type(int) is type ---->
True`

Comment: would you please explain how?

Comment: The full answer is here: [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949). `type` is the default metaclass.

Comment: `int` is a type, and the type of a type is a metaclass. Instances of a metaclass are types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` IS a type name (class name), while `1` is an object of type int

And `"int"` would be a string.

Check:

```
type(1) is int
type(int) is type
type("int") is str
type(str) is type
type(type) is type
```

Some build-in types are `int`, `str`, `float`, `list`, `set`, `dict`... And yes, all those names by themselves are of type `type`

Answer (score 2):

`int` itself is a type

```py
type(0)
#int

type(int)
#type
```

Your example is no different to

```py
print(type(type(0)))
```